# Get the word start and end position

Tags: java, android, string, textview

So I am trying to highlight the text view based on words but my code is not working properly what i want to do is "Hello world" both the word comes in different colour but for me only the hello part is getting highlighted

```
  SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(all_folder.get(position).getAudioChineseText());
            String spannableword = all_folder.get(position).getAudioChineseText();
            String[] splitStr = spannableword.split("\\s+");
            int end = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < splitStr.length; i++) {
                end = splitStr[i].length() + i;
                int start=splitStr[i].length()+1;
                textcolor(holder.textChines, spannableString, i, end, all_folder.get(position).getSpeechResponse());

            }
```

the textcolour method is working fine but the position is not getting passed properly any idea what i am doing wrong as i need to pass the start and end position of the word

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of `String#lastIndexOf` and `String#indexOf` to get the spanned index. Below is an example .

```
private SpannableString getSpanString(String text){
    SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(text);
    int startIndex1= 0;
    int endIndex1= text.indexOf(" ");
    int startIndex2= text.lastIndexOf(" ");
    int endIndex2 = text.length();
    spannableString.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), startIndex1, endIndex1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    spannableString.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), startIndex2, endIndex2, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    return spannableString;
}
```

Of course you need handle the edge cases here first . Like if String only have one word or its blank but the idea remain the same. Give it a try after adding the edge cases in the beginning of the method . Also you have to trim the string before use.

Answer (score -1):

Don't use `split()` if you want the positions in the original string, use a `find()` loop instead.

```java
String spannableword = "Hello World";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\S+").matcher(spannableword);
while (m.find()) {
    String str = m.group();
    int start = m.start();
    int end = m.end();
    System.out.printf("Found word (%d - %d): '%s'%n", start, end, str);
}
```

*Output*

```
Found word (0 - 5): 'Hello'
Found word (6 - 11): 'World'
```

Note how the regex used is `\\S+`, the opposite of the split regex `\\s+`.